# For loop in Python goes wrong

Tags: python, for-loop

I have mutation status (`0`,`1`) for ten genes in ten cancer 3D models

I have also gene expression in these 3D models, like

```r
expr1 <- structure(list(GeneA_KO = c(0.0756383119639074, -0.162841965682723, -0.110703100204517, -0.457154616239399, -0.505815193885352, 0.366072775033448, 0.288650458935083, -0.0287646498640309, -0.690732824311905, 0.157366122620995, -1.29451546737684, 0.124167425460344, -0.168045313861751, 0.0186504943306465, -0.495880827400706, -0.206668627339351, -0.148609490335447, 0.066844529089804), GeneB_KO = c(-0.870157285953621, -0.35900872537626, -0.990406888128838, -0.120656981579292, -1.41427631791049, -0.866421095836781, -0.816936112146099, -0.894597236248507, -1.00084584207823, -0.850754488133456, -1.05314239761653, -1.07580675428372, -1.24708324665688, -1.04098460460899, -0.232388675985086, -1.48513703581865, -1.48373348870346, -1.76484058374354)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ModelM", "ModelO", "ModelS", "ModelA", "ModelI", "ModelC", "ModelT", "ModelH", "ModelE", "ModelR", "ModelA2", "ModelP", "ModelE2", "ModelU", "ModelT2", "ModelC2", "ModelS2", "ModelX"))
mut <- structure(list(ModelM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ModelH = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ModelE = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelR = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ModelA2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelE2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelU = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ModelT2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelC2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),     ModelS2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1_mut", "Gene2_mut", "Gene3_mut", "Gene4_mut", "Gene5_mut", "Gene6_mut", "Gene7_mut", "Gene8_mut", "Gene9_mut", "Gene10_mut"))
```

`mut.csv` and `expr1.csv` exported for use in Python:

```r
write.csv(mut, "mut.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(expr1[1:10,], "expr1.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

I want to do a one-way ANOVA in Python so that calculate P-VALUE for each pair of mutation-expression in each pair of gene-model

This code returns error

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm
m = pd.read_csv("mut.csv", sep=",")
m=pd.DataFrame(m)
m.info()
g = pd.read_csv("expr1.csv", sep=",")
g=pd.DataFrame(g)

lst = list(g.columns)
m_lst = list(m.columns)

dfs = pd.DataFrame({})
for Mut in m_lst:
    for Model in lst:
        df = pd.concat([m[[Mut]].reset_index(drop=True), g[[Model]].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={Mut: "mut", Model: "g"})
        model = ols('g ~ C(mut)', data=df).fit()
ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (10, 18)

        aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
        aov_table[['Model']] = Model
        aov_table[['Mut']] = Mut
        dfs = dfs.append(aov_table)
```

The ideal output is something like

```py
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(dfs)
            sum_sq   df         F    PR(>F)     Model      Mut
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelM
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelM
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelM
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelM
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelO
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelO
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're wanting to do, I can see bugs but the key bit of output is missing (below). It seems a bit weird to me the nested loop in context, but thats fine if you're happy.

The critical step is this

```
df = pd.concat([m[[Mut]].reset_index(drop=True), g[[Model]].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

What I'm concerned about is the `pd.concat`. Are you sure `pd.concat` is the right command here? I thought `m` is one data table, e.g. mutation and `g` is another e.g. expression. `pd.concat` isn't going to work here, are you sure this isn't a `merge` or `join` command?

Anyway, the fitting is complaining the `.shape()` is wrong. Needs reshaping? Thats the error. Printing `df` at that point would be needed.

> ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (10, 18)

To summarise normally the error you have received is about re-shaping the data. I've not put forward that solution here because,

- I am not sure what the data represents
- If I was doing this I wouldn't use `pd.concat`

It seems a lot of columns for a 1-way ANOVA, but could be right, I've not done 1-way ANOVA across 10 columns.

*Bug 1*

```
m = pd.read_csv("mut.csv", sep=",")
m=pd.DataFrame(m)
m.info()
g = pd.read_csv("expr1.csv", sep=",")
g=pd.DataFrame(g)
```

This should simply be:

```
m = pd.read_csv("mut.csv")
g = pd.read_csv("expr1.csv")
```

*Bug 2?*

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame({})
...
dfs = dfs.append(aov_table)
```

This will work given `aov_table` output is a pandas dataframe (I'm not at all sure it is). You need `aov_table.info()` to be sure. You can always place it in a dataframe however.